# Is A Non-destructive Workflow Possible Between Photoshop and Lightroom?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, adobe-lightroom

Is it possible to work on an image from Lightroom in Photoshop whilst maintaining a link to the original file so that if I make changes to the original file in Lightroom, those changes will be reflected in the Photoshop document?

Opening as a smart object breaks the link to the original file, effectively embedding a copy into the Photoshop document.

Comment: PS CC has "[Linked smart object](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html#create-linked-smart-objects)". It works pretty much the same as linked files in Illustrator and Indesign.

Comment: @Joonas Thanks, but how does this work with Lightroom? What is the workflow? Lightroom doesn't allow you to 'Open as Linked Smart Object'

Comment: This is a feature in photoshop. Hasn't got anything to do with Lightroom  directly. It allows you to place image to photoshop and then updates it automatically as the file is changed.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I have seen to what you want to do is one of the plugins from Jeffrey Friedl. Take a look at his Photoshop Layers plugin:

http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/layers